# peer.id not getting created - PeerJS

Tags: peerjs

I am doing a video chat app, in which I am creating a peer object in index.html.
**Below is the code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GeekChat</title>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/peerjs/0.3.14/peer.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'>


    </div>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script src='/io-square/io-square-browser.js'></script>
    <script>
      window.socket = io.connect()
      window.peer = new Peer({host: 'peerjs-server.herokuapp.com', secure: true, port: 443})
    </script>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I am accessing peer.id at some other point in the app. the whole peer object with 7 properties gets created, but the id doesn't get created.

At later point when I access window.peer.id on the browser developer tools, I am able to access it.

Can anybody please let me know when does the peer id actually gets created.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the peer ID in the 'open' event listener on the peer.

```
window.peer.on('open', function(id){
       //handle the id
   });
```